# An alternative way to calculate $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x}{x^2+(1-x)^2}\,dx$

Tags: calculus, alternative-proof

Consider the integral
$$
\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x}{x^2+(1-x)^2}\,dx
$$
By noting that
$$
\frac{x}{x^2+(1-x)^2}=
\frac{2x-1}{(2x-1)^2+1}+\frac{1}{(2x-1)^2+1}
$$
we deduce
$$
\int\frac{x}{x^2+(1-x)^2}\,dx=\frac{\ln(x^2+(1-x)^2)}{4}+\frac{1}{2}\arctan(2x-1)+C,
$$
so
$$
\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x}{x^2+(1-x)^2}\,dx=\frac{\pi}{4}.
$$
Is there an alternative way to calculate this integral?

Comment: How do you "notice that" $
\frac{x}{x^2+(1-x)^2}=
\frac{2x-1}{(2x-1)^2+1}+\frac{1}{(2x-1)^2+1}
$? Unless that was given and that's why you were looking for an alternate method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[A trick](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3856735/why-does-the-king-property-of-integration-work): use $\int_0^1f(x)dx=\int_0^1f(1-x)dx$ to average two versions of your integral, reducing it to$$\tfrac12\left(\int_0^1\tfrac{xdx}{x^2+(1-x)^2}+\int_0^1\tfrac{(1-x)dx}{x^2+(1-x)^2}\right)=\tfrac12\int_0^1\tfrac{dx}{x^2+(1-x)^2}.$$

Comment: Nice (for sure). Now, no more bounds, just the antiderivative. Cheers and $\to +1$.

Comment: For further aniderivative, it becomes $\tfrac12\int_0^1\tfrac{dx}{x^2+(1-x)^2}=-\tfrac12\int_0^1\tfrac{d({1\over x}-1)}{1+({1\over x}-1)^2}=\tfrac12\arctan\infty={\pi\over 4}$

Comment: Would you be able to further explain how you implemented the King property?

Comment: @user71207 See edit.

Comment: Also @ClaudeLeibovici what do you mean by "no more bounds"? Aren;t the bounds still $1$ to $0$?

Comment: @user71207. I was just trying to mean that, until the end, we don't need to care about them. Thats's all.

Comment: oh yes that is true

Answer (score 2):

$$I=\int\frac{x}{x^2+(1-x)^2}\,dx=\int \frac{x}{2x^2-2x+1}\,dx=\int \frac{x}{2(x-a)(x-b)}\,dx$$
$$I=\frac 1{2(a-b)}\int \Big[\frac a{x-a}-\frac b{x-b} \Big]\,dx$$
$$I=\frac 1{2(a-b)}\Big[a \log(|x-a|)-b\log(|x-b|)\Big]$$ Now $a=\frac{1-i}2$, $b=\frac{1+i}2$,
$$I=\frac {1-i}4\left(\log
   \left(x-\frac{1+i}{2}\right)+i \log
   \left(x-\frac{1-i}{2}\right)\right)$$

Use the bounds, play with the complex numbers to get the answer.