# Evaluate $y\ =\int_{o}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\left(\sqrt{\sin x}\right)}{\sqrt{\sin x\ }+\sqrt{\cos x}}dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I have tried applying the formulas but unfortunately not getting close.

Comment: [Hint](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3856735).

Comment: You should briefly list the formulas you tried applying. It gives a better understanding of what you need help with and what you don’t need help with. In general, the more effort you put in your question, the more effort we’ll put in our answers (and vice versa). ;)