# Calculate integral with continuous function

Tags: integration, functions

$$\int_0^1\frac{f(x)}{f(x) + f(1- x)}dx$$if we know that $$ f > 0, f - continuous function $$

Comment: Hint: Make a change of variable $y = 1-x$

Comment: @NN2's advice is a special case of the [King property](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3856735/why-does-the-king-property-of-integration-work),$$\int_a^bf(x)dx=\int_a^bf(a+b-x)dx=\int_a^b[pf(x)+(1-p)f(a+b-x)]dx$$(of which the case $p=\frac12$ is the most frequently useful).

Comment: ... and "King property"  is a term that seems to be used only in India.  But @NN2's advice is applicable the world over.

Answer (score 3):

using u=1-x you get the following:
$$I=-\int_1^0 \frac{f(1-u)}{f(1-u)+f(u)}du=\int_0^1\frac{f(1-x)}{f(1-x)+f(x)}dx  $$
so now:

$$2I =  \int_0^1\frac{f(1-x)}{f(1-x)+f(x)}dx + \int_0^1\frac{f(x)}{f(x)+f(1-x)}dx=\int_0^1 1dx=1-0$$
so I=1/2