# An interesting trigonometric integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, contest-math, trigonometric-integrals

Yesterday I took part in an entry competition to one of the MSc programs in my university, and during one of the mathematical tests, I had to solve some integral and differential equations.

One of those integrals had the following trigonometric form:
$$
I(0,\pi)= \int\limits_0^\pi\left[\cos^2(\cos(x))+\sin^2(\sin(x))\right]dx
$$
Unfortunately, I didn’t manage to solve it analytically during the test, but later, as I came home, I tried to evaluate it numerically using Mathematica. As it turned out, the answer seems to be $I(0,\pi)=\pi$.

Still, I do not understand what transformations or substitutions I had to perform so that to solve this problem analytically during the exam. This is exactly the reason, I am posting my question here, as I haven’t found this kind of problem even posted or solved anywhere yet, and so I am kindly asking for any help to attempt this integral analytically.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you mean $\left[\cos(\cos(x))\right]^2+\left[\sin(\sin(x))\right]^2$ or $\cos\left[(\cos(x))^2\right]+\sin\left[(\sin(x))^2\right]$ ? If it is the first one, then I guess the answer is quite obviously $\pi$...

Comment: Both Cases are not Obvious to me , @TheSilverDoe , It might be Obvious when the Outer $\sin$ & $\cos$ have Same argument which is not true here.

Comment: @Prem Oops, indeed, nothing obvious here. But my first question still stands...

Comment: I checked the 2 Cases & figured out which way we get $\pi$ , @TheSilverDoe , I updated the Question to match that.

Comment: @o.spectrum FYI, an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Cint_0%5E%5Cpi(%5Ccos%5E2(%5Ccos(x))%2B%5Csin%5E2(%5Csin(x)))dx%24&p=1) found multiple AoPS threads for your integral, but only with an upper bound of $\frac{\pi}{2}$, e.g., [Sine of sine and cosine of cosine](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h2008562p14069734), [Fun integral](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h1470363p8529417), [Integral](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h1715003p11074336), ...

Comment: @o.spectrum (cont.) [How to solve this integral](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h1295167p6869009), [Integral of Trig Functions](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h589696p3492223), etc.

Comment: @JohnOmielan oh wow, thank you so much! I didn’t even know about such a source, it seems like it will help me a lot in the future!

Comment: Mathematica seems to be unable to solve the general integral, if there is no known closed formula, the proof probably had to rely on the particular choice of the interval $[0,\pi]$ which guides exploration to "what tricks can I use that involve $\pi$ $\cos$ and $\sin$ to integrate this". A youtube video I saw mentioned that these kinds of integrals with definite bounds often have a solution using the "king's property" (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3856735/1049002) and so seeing that "it looks too complicated" and the definite bounds, my mind went to "looks like a king's property"

Comment: about searching for fomulas online, there was this question about it but I do not know much about the last answer at the bottom https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10169/1049002

Answer (score 48, accepted):

\begin{align*}
I&= \int_0^\pi \cos^2\cos x+\sin^2\sin x \, dx\\
&= 2\int_0^{\pi/2}  \cos^2\cos x+\sin^2\sin x \, dx\\
&= 2\int_0^{\pi/2} \cos^2\sin x+\sin^2\cos x \, dx \quad(x\mapsto\pi/2-x)\\
\end{align*}
Hence
$$ 2I=2\int_0^{ \pi/2 } 2\, dx\Rightarrow I=\pi $$
from summing the last two lines.

Comment: Could you please motivate why it is obvious that $\int_0^{\pi}=2\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}$

Comment: Because the integrand is invariant under $x\mapsto \pi-x$, i.e. symmetric about $x=\pi/2$.

Comment: @Goonfiend oh, what an answer! Thank you so much. Now I feel awkward for not noticing that we can transform the arguments so that for them to match what further allows for the Pythagorean identity to be applied. At least now I finally see it, maybe the cause was that I was short on time during the exam. Anyways, thank you for this beautiful answer once again!

Comment: I am adding the @ for @Zima so that they get a notification about Goonfiend's reply.

Comment: If you split over the $+$, apply the $x \mapsto \pi/2 - x$ substitution only to the second half of the integral ($\sin^2 \sin x$), and combine again, you end up with $2\int_0^{\pi/2} \cos^2 \cos x + \sin^2 \cos x\ dx = 2\int_0^{\pi/2} 1\ dx = 2\tfrac\pi2 = \pi$ without needing to double.

Comment: @userrandrand thank you

Comment: @tomsmeding then you have different bounds on each piece, $[0,\pi]$ and $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$, how will you combine again without using symmetry ?

Comment: @userrandrand er, like this? https://tomsmeding.com/ss/get/tomsmeding/Pn2jve I _am_ using symmetry in the same way as Goonfiend, but then being more frugal in applying the substitution.

Answer (score 17):

A slightly different approach :

\begin{align*}
I&= \int_0^\pi \cos^2\cos x+\sin^2\sin x \, dx\\
& = \int_0^\pi \dfrac{1+\cos(2\cos(x))}{2} + \dfrac{1-\cos(2\sin(x))}{2} dx \\
& = \pi + \dfrac{1}{2} \left( \int_0^\pi \cos(2 \cos(x)) dx - \int_0^\pi \cos(2 \sin(x)) dx\right) \\
\end{align*}

But notice that
\begin{align*}
\int_0^\pi \cos(2 \cos(x)) dx & = \int_0^{\pi/2}   \cos(2 \cos(x)) dx  + \int_{\pi/2}^\pi \cos(2 \cos(x)) dx \\
& = \int_{\pi/2}^{\pi} \cos(2 \sin(u)) du + \int_0^{\pi/2} \cos(2 \sin(t)) dt \\
& \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad (\text{substituting } u=x + \dfrac{\pi}{2} \text{ and } t=x- \dfrac{\pi}{2})\\
& = \int_0^{\pi} \cos(2 \sin(x)) dx
\end{align*}

and you are done.

Comment: Oh, wow, that’s quite an interesting approach as well! Thank you so much for sharing it :)

Answer (score 14):

Let's take a completely different approach. Set

$$f(x)=\cos^2\cos x+\sin^2\sin x-1.$$

We will show that $f$ integrates to $0$ over $[0,\pi]$. Observe that

\begin{align*}
f\left(x+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)
&=\cos^2\cos\left(x+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)+\sin^2\sin\left(x+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)-1\\
&=\cos^2\sin x+\sin^2\cos x-1\\
&=\left(1-\sin^2\sin x\right)+\left(1-\cos^2\cos x\right)-1 \\
&=1-\cos^2\cos x-\sin^2\sin x\\
&=-f(x).
\end{align*}

Indeed this property alone is enough to show the result, as then

\begin{align*}
\int_0^\pi f(x)~\mathrm{d}x
&=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} f(x)~\mathrm{d}x+\int_\frac{\pi}{2}^\pi f(x)~\mathrm{d}x \\
&=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} f(x)~\mathrm{d}x+\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} f\left(x+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)~\mathrm{d}x \\
&=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}(f(x)-f(x))~\mathrm{d}x \\
&=0.
\end{align*}

The result in the question now follows by observing that

$$\int_0^\pi\bigl(\cos^2\cos x+\sin^2\sin x\bigr)~\mathrm{d}x=\underbrace{\int_0^\pi f(x)~\mathrm{d}x}_{=0}+\underbrace{\int_0^\pi\mathrm{d}x}_{=\pi}=\pi.$$

Comment: I like this approach. +1. Very satisfying to get the integral to 0

Answer (score 7):

Under $\cos x\to x$, one has
\begin{align*}
I&= \int_0^\pi (\cos^2\cos x+\sin^2\sin x) \, dx\\
& = \int_{-1}^1 \dfrac{\cos^2x+\sin^2(\sqrt{1-x^2})}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} dx \\
& = 2\int_{0}^1 \dfrac{\cos^2x+\sin^2(\sqrt{1-x^2})}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} dx.
\end{align*}
Noting that, under $\sqrt{1-x^2}\to x$, one has
$$\int_{0}^1 \dfrac{\sin^2(\sqrt{1-x^2})}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} dx=\int_{0}^1 \dfrac{\sin^2x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} dx$$
and hence
$$ I=2\int_{0}^1 \dfrac{\cos^2x+\sin^2x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} dx=2\int_{0}^1 \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} dx=\pi. $$

Answer (score 2):

Here is a method using Bessel functions. This is most likely not viable in a competition, but if you know the expansions and realize the simplifications due to the $\sin(2\pi k)$ factor, it may work.
$$\begin{align*}
I(0,\pi)&=\int_0^\pi\cos^2(\cos x)+\sin^2(\sin x)\ dx \\
&=\int_0^\pi\cos^2(\cos x)\ dx+\int_0^\pi\sin^2(\sin x)\ dx \\
&=\int_0^\pi\frac{1+\cos(2\cos x)}{2}\ dx+\int_0^\pi\frac{1-\cos(2\sin x)}{2}\ dx\\
&=\pi+\frac{1}{2}\underbrace{\int_0^\pi\cos(2\cos x)\ dx}_{I_1}-\frac{1}{2}\underbrace{\int_0^\pi\cos(2\sin x)\ dx}_{I_2}
\end{align*}$$
Using two Jacobi-Anger [expansions](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.12),
$$\cos(2\cos x)=J_0(2)+2\sum_{k=1}^\infty(-1)^kJ_{2k}(2)\cos(2kx),\quad x\in\mathbb{C} \\
\cos(2\sin x)=J_0(2)+2\sum_{k=1}^\infty J_{2k}(2)\cos(2kx),\quad x\in\mathbb{C}$$
we have for $I_1$,
$$\begin{align*}I_1&=\int_0^\pi J_0(2)+2\sum_{k=1}^\infty(-1)^kJ_{2k}(2)\cos(2kx)\ dx \\&=\pi J_0(2)+2\sum_{k=1}^\infty(-1)^kJ_{2k}(2)\int_0^\pi\cos(2kx)\ dx\\
&=\pi J_0(2)+2\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^kJ_{2k}(2)\sin(2\pi k)}{k} \\&=\pi J_0(2)
\end{align*}$$
and for $I_2$,
$$\begin{align*}
I_2&=\int_0^\pi J_0(2)+2\sum_{k=1}^\infty J_{2k}(2)\cos(2kx)\ dx \\
&=\pi J_0(2)+2\sum_{k=1}^\infty J_{2k}(2)\int_0^\pi\cos(2kx)\ dx \\
&=\pi J_0(2)+2\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{J_{2k}(2)\sin(2\pi k)}{k} \\
&=\pi J_0(2)
\end{align*}$$
thus the integral is,
$$I(0,\pi)=\pi+\frac{\pi }{2}J_0(2)-\frac{\pi}{2}J_0(2)=\pi.$$

---

Another solution, this time utilizing the Maclaurin expansion of $\cos(x)$. As we end up finding closed forms in terms of the Bessel function anyways, I will merge answers.

Working similarly as above,
$$\begin{align*}
I(0,\pi)&=\pi+\frac{1}{2}\underbrace{\int_0^\pi\cos(2\cos x)\ dx}_{I_1}-\frac{1}{2}\underbrace{\int_0^\pi\cos(2\sin x)\ dx}_{I_2}
\end{align*}$$
expanding the cosine by its Maclaurin series,
$$I_1=\int_0^\pi\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k2^{2k}}{(2k)!}\cos^{2k}(x)\ dx=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k2^{2k}}{(2k)!}\int_0^\pi\cos^{2k}(x)\ dx=\pi\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{(k!)^2}=\pi J_0(2)$$
$$I_2=\int_0^\pi\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k2^{2k}}{(2k)!}\sin^{2k}(x)\ dx=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k2^{2k}}{(2k)!}\int_0^\pi\sin^{2k}(x)\ dx=\pi\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{(k!)^2}=\pi J_0(2)$$
here I used the [Wallis integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis%27_integrals#Another_relation_to_evaluate_the_Wallis%27_integrals),
$$\int_0^\pi\cos^{2k}(x)\ dx=\int_0^\pi\sin^{2k}(x)\ dx=\frac{\pi}{2^{2k}}\binom{2k}{k},\quad k\in\mathbb{Z_0}$$
and the [series expansion](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Series_Expansion_of_Bessel_Function_of_the_First_Kind) for the Bessel function of first kind,
$$J_0(z)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{(k!)^2}\left(\frac{z}{2}\right)^{2k},\quad z\in\mathbb{C}$$
hence by similar arguments,
$$I(0,\pi)=\pi.$$