# Calculate: $\int_{-2}^{2}\frac{x^2}{e^x+1}~dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

$$\int_{-2}^{2}\frac{x^2}{e^x+1}~dx$$
Options:

a) $\; 0$

b) $\; \frac{e-2}{e}$

c) $\; \frac{8}{3}$

d) $\; \frac{e-1}{e}$

e) $\; \frac{16}{3}$

Note: It's high school level

What I tried:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! Please consider taking the time to read the [faq](https://math.stackexchange.com/faq) to familiarise yourself with some of our common practices. In addition, [this page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) should give you a start at learning how to typeset mathematics here so that your posts say what you want them to, and also look good. As this question appears to be homework, please consider reading [this page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1803) for information about asking _effective_ homework-related questions. Cheers!

Comment: [This graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/kusvpk5tm4) indicates that the value of the integral should be kinda close to 2.5 and 8/3 is the only choice that fills that criterion. Note: While I generated the graph using Desmos for illustrative purposes, don't think it's too hard to come up with the picture without software.

Comment: What is your high school?:)

Comment: This integral is [on AoPS](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h1879401p12780939)

Comment: @TymaGaidash thanks a lot :)

Comment: If the problem is multiple choice and targeted at high schoolers, then you should absolutely consider a geometric approach. In this problem, it literally takes a minute or two. That's probably the point from the problem writer's perspective.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $x \mapsto -x$ (this is the same as letting $u = -x $ then renaming $u$ as $x$).

$\displaystyle I = \int_{-2}^{2}\frac{x^2}{e^x+1}~dx = -\int_{2}^{-2}\frac{x^2}{e^{-x}+1}~dx = \int_{-2}^{2}\frac{x^2}{e^{-x}+1}~dx$

Adding the first and last integrals together and using $\frac{1}{y+1}+\frac{1}{y^{-1}+1} = 1$:

$\displaystyle 2I = \int_{-2}^{2}\frac{x^2}{e^x+1}~dx + \int_{-2}^{2}\frac{x^2}{e^{-x}+1}~dx = \int_{-2}^{2} x^2 dx  = \frac{16}{3}$

So that $\displaystyle {I = \frac{8}{3}}$.

Comment: I recently learned that this trick is called [the King's property](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3856735/why-does-the-king-property-of-integration-work)

Comment: @DavidRaveh  It has discrete versions:

$$\displaystyle \sum_{k=a}^{b}f(k) = \sum_{k=a}^{b}f(a+b-k)$$

$$\displaystyle \prod_{k=a}^{b}f(k) = \prod_{k=a}^{b}f(a+b-k)$$

Comment: This solution was already in the link to AoPS provided above by @TymaGaidash, but it is good to have it here.

Comment: @AnneBauval It's a standard trick

Comment: I am used to it.