# Integral of Choose functions

Tags: integration, combinatorics, gamma-function

MIT Integration Question:
Find: $$\int_{0}^{4} \begin{pmatrix} x \\ 5\end{pmatrix} dx$$
I know this might be somewhat simplified using the Gamma Function, however is there any simpler way to find this integral?

Comment: ${n \choose 5}$ is just a constant.  The answer is 4 times that.

Comment: Do you mean $\int_0^4 \binom{x}{5} \ dx$?

Comment: If you mean $\int_0^4\binom x5dx$ is just a polynomial. A bit annoying to compute with pen and paper, but rather straight forward.

Comment: More specifically, for complex $n$ and natural $r$ we have the generalized definition (*which is the only interpretation that makes sense here*) that $\binom{n}{r} = \dfrac{n^{\underline{r}}}{r!}$ where $n^{\underline{r}}$ is the falling factorial notation.  That is to say, $\binom{x}{5} = \dfrac{1}{5!}\times x(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-4)$.  Gamma function has nothing to do with this.

Comment: Hint: [King's rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3856735) implies this integral is $0$.

Answer (score 3):

Just use the definition of [the generalized binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Generalization_and_connection_to_the_binomial_series):
$$\int_{0}^{4}\binom{x}{5}dx
 =\frac{1}{5!}\int_{0}^{4}x\left(x-1\right)\left(x-2\right)\left(x-3\right)\left(x-4\right)dx=0$$

Comment: To be clear, the definition does not in fact involve factorials with $x$, noting that $x$ might not be a whole number.

Comment: @JMoravitz I know, but in fact the question is not even asked correctly given that the binomial coefficient is not a continuous function if only integers are to be considered, so the integral does not make sense. I think it's more of one of those "try having some fun by thinking outside the box" questions.

Comment: There does exist the generalized binomial coefficient which I alluded to already above in my comments which allows for any complex value for the top number, in particular any reals in the interval $[0,4]$.  The end result is that your final expression you write is the correct simplification, but you got there by using an incorrect definition and interpretation of the binomial coefficient.

Comment: Again, that is wrong.  [The generalized binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Generalization_and_connection_to_the_binomial_series) $\binom{x}{r}$ is defined for any complex $x$ and natural $r$ and when treated as a function of $x$ is indeed continuous.